# Setting android:launchmode for UnityPlayerActivity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-activity, android-manifest, launchmode

I'm building an Android game on Unity which has a button that opens a new activity.

The problem is when building the APK, no matter what I put in my custom AndroidManifest.xml, Unity overrides it and sets android:launchMode for `com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity` to `singleTask`.

This results in the following scenario: Open the game, tap the button that opens the activity, tap the home button to go to background, relaunch the app using the icon - the new activity is destroyed and instead I see the same main UnityPlayerActivity (it's the same original one - nothing has been recreated).

In order to fix it - I had to create the apk, decompile it using apktool, hardcode `android:launchMode=0` for `com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity` (which means `standard` instead of `singleTask`), recompile it, resign it, and only then install it.

This is obviously a total hack and can't be used as an actual solution. I need to find a way to set the `android:launchMode` myself.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried exporting your project to android studio?

Comment: post your manifest please

Answer (score 1):

After investigating the issue, I found that the reason for this behaviour is that Unity is setting the launchMode on the AndroidManifest.xml for the UnityPlayerActivity to be singleTask.

When the app launches a new activity, which is – in the instance of launchMode:singleTask – closed in case of a relaunch.

No matter what we set in our custom AndroidManifest.xml, Unity will just override it to be singleTask and according to the official Unity Documentation – Unity only supports launchMode:singleTask.