# My Activity disappeared after recenter via launch icon

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile, android-activity

## Prerequisites

I had a Unity project,then I built it into a Android apk.

There is some code can launch a new Activity.

By default, SceneA is shown.

## Question

Then,I switch to Home Screen,then switch back.

The SceneA is shown, but BActivity is disappered.

I want keep BActivity shown.

Any sugesstion?

## Replenish 1:

when I switch back to App from Home Screen, My custom activity BAcitivity is destoried.

It called `onDestroy` but not called `onResume`.

## Replenish 2:

There is some different between `Pure Android` and `Unity Android`.

```
Pure Android
    launch KeepActivity
        KeepActivity onCreate
        KeepActivity onStart
        KeepActivity onResume
        handleWindowFocusChanged mWindowFocusChanged true mUpcomingWindowFocus true mAdded true

    switch to Home Screen
        handleWindowFocusChanged mWindowFocusChanged true mUpcomingWindowFocus false mAdded true
        KeepActivity onPause
        setWindowStopped stopped:true
        KeepActivity onStop

    switch back to App
        KeepActivity onRestart
        KeepActivity onStart
        KeepActivity onResume
        handleWindowFocusChanged mWindowFocusChanged true mUpcomingWindowFocus true mAdded true

Unity Android
    launch KeepActivity
        KeepActivity onCreate UnityPlayer.currentActivity:com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity@468f2d3
        KeepActivity onResume
        handleWindowFocusChanged mWindowFocusChanged true mUpcomingWindowFocus true mAdded true

    switch to Home Screen
        handleWindowFocusChanged mWindowFocusChanged true mUpcomingWindowFocus false mAdded true
        KeepActivity onPause

    switch back to App
        KeepActivity onDestroy
```

## Solution

The reason is `UnityPlayerActivity` has `android:launchMode="singleTask"`.(It happens not matter Unity and Android.)

just remove it, the problem can be resolved.

But I don't know if there will be other problems.

Comment: It seems that your app consumes too many system resources and it was killed by the OS while being in the background.

Comment: Even I create a new unity project with less resouce, It still happened. It seems like a Unity bug or something. I hope there is a way to keep BActivity alive.

Comment: I don't think that is the Unity3d bug. There are too many apps built using it to ignore such a bug. You can also check your manifest settings as it is described here https://forum.unity.com/threads/app-is-restarted-when-re-launched.245062/

Comment: It seems is a post from 2014，now I use UnityPlayerActivity as a launcher Activity. And I don't changed the manifest file. and UnityPlayerActivity is not destoried, The problem is BActivity is destoried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-launchmode-why-does-unity-have-it-as-singletask.992683/

[Setting android:launchmode for UnityPlayerActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50878122/setting-androidlaunchmode-for-unityplayeractivity)

[App restarts rather than resumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545889/app-restarts-rather-than-resumes/23220151#23220151)

## Solution

The reason is `UnityPlayerActivity` has `android:launchMode="singleTask"`.(It happens not matter Unity and Android.)

just remove it, the problem can be resolved.

But I don't know if there will be other problems.